# Forcing Event Listener in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, events, dom-events, addeventlistener

I have added a touch start event listener to a image.

```
Image.addEventListener('touchstart', myFunction);
```

My question is, is it possible to force a fake `touchstart`/`touchend` to occur on my image, without it actually happening? I already know I could simply call the function again whenever I like, I need to actually fake its properties to say a `touchend` has occurred.

Answer (score 1):

Check out this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2490876/1167867)

> You can use fireEvent on IE, and w3c's dispatchEvent on most other
>   browsers. To create the event you want to fire, you can use either
>   createEvent or createEventObject depending on the browser.

Answer (score 0):

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/Events/Creating_and_triggering_events

```
var touchStart = new Event('touchstart');
Image.addEventListener('touchstart', myFunction);

Image.dispatchEvent(touchStart);
```